# How to resize button without cutting the text inside

Tags: html, css

I am trying to style my button however when I try to resize it via height or width attributes it keeps cutting the text inside. I tried using paddings as well but I am having no luck.

Here are some pictures for my problem

[image]

I want the height of the blue area to be smaller and the "x" centered within the square.

[image]

css code for above is

```
.delete {
 cursor: pointer !important;
 font-size: 42px;
 position: absolute;
 color: gray;   
 height: 50px;
}
```

[image]

css code for this one is

```
.delete {
 cursor: pointer !important;
 font-size: 42px;
 position: absolute;
 color: gray;   
 height: 30px;
}
```

How do I style the button to get it to move the "x" text up the way I  want?

Here is my html

```
<button type="button" class="delete" ng-click="deleteModel(model)">
      <span>&times;</span>
      <span class="sr-only">Delete</span>
</button>
```

Comment: are u using a sprite image for get the X image?

Comment: no the "X" is an `&times;` I edited in my actual html code in the question.

Comment: Oh i see, you are using that character, try to reduce the font size of that span, because "&times;" is a character not a image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `line-height`

```
line-height:25px;
```

You may need to play around with the value. 25px looks good with your code.

http://jsfiddle.net/686s8/

Comment: It was totally the line-height. Thanks Joe!

Answer (score 1):

try out this css:

```
.delete {
cursor: pointer !important;
position: absolute;
color: gray;   
height: 36px;
}
.delete span{
font-size:28px;
}
```

It might help you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here, you need to reduce the size of the font, because that is a character not an image.

try with:

```
 font-size: 25px;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3Yq8P/

Comment: Your answer has my jsFiddle link, please change to your example.

Comment: yep sorry, i changed it.